# c# search a string for anything that relates to query

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Using search bar in xamarin forms...

returns to code behind when text is changed...

in the search query I can get exact matches to return with .Contains()....but if other text is added it is removed from the suggestions popdown.

So for example

```
return Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text));
```

so In the Products list say we have 'book'...if the user enters b or bo or boo or book, 'book' will appear on the search query...however if the user enters 'book m'...or 'm book'. the query will not return book. If any of the text entered matches anything in the products list I want it returned on the query.

how would I do this? create a substring of text entered and match it against substring of products list?

also would like to ignore casing

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to this :

```
  return Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(text)|| text.Contains(p.Name));
```